# Restrict the amount of space a folder can use

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, file-management, restrictions, virtual-disk

I have a directory I have given write access to `everyone` and shared it for the LAN (for easy distribution of files within my sharehouse). I want to be able to remove any chance that my drive will fill up unexpectedly (by people copying copious amounts of data).
Is there some security setting I could set on it that will reject any writes if the folder has reached a certain size?

Another idea I thought of would be to make a new partition on the disk, and then share the resultant drive, which would have a fixed size. But that's way too inflexible (waht if I wanted to increase the cap?) and too much hassle (my physical drive is currently fully utilised as a single partition).

Going on from that idea, though, is there a way I can create a virtual drive, and have that map to a directory? Because I'm guessing I could force the size constraint on the virtual volume and share/only write to that.

Comment: See this SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532775/is-it-possible-to-limit-folder-size-in-a-windows-environment

Comment: thanks for the response. If you could [in an answer] adequately explain how I could use [quotas](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/76002-disk-quota-set-space-limits-users.html) for my above scenario I would much appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Using the notions in my answer you can use [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5291/how-to-create-a-virtual-hard-drive-in-windows-7/) tutorial I later found to set up a `Virtual Hard Disk`. It explains how you can create, initialise and format a `VHD` from the `Computer Management` tool.

Unfortunately the `VHD` is stored as a file, meaning the disk actually has it's own file format and structure. So you can't access the files without going through the mounted disk. It is not a simple high-level map to a real directory on a host disk (which I'm sure there would be software out there for, and would be ideal).

This solution works natively without third party software and is not as inflexible as creating a real partition on another drive.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing so is to go to the 'properties' of the volume and configure 'Quota management.

-> my computer
-> local disk (c:) or whatever volume you are using for the share
-> Right-Click Properties
-> quota
-> quota management

Comment: How would this work in my case where the user is `everyone`? I don't want to restrict this user class only to cause issues when I run things to write to other directories in that drive which may utilise this user.